# how to get over with error in filestream image

Tags: vb.net

I get this error when a user does not select an image:

[image]

1. How can I get rid of this error?
2. How can I also call and save an image in resources named "uersadd" if the user does not select an image?

Here is my code: [image]

thanks

Comment: You should add the code as text in the post, rather than an image.

Comment: Next time try Ctrl+Shft+Alt+PrintScreen to auto-crop.

Comment: One question at a time

Comment: I love your optimism Kwabena Anko, don't let anyone take that away from you! However, you should do as @bencripps says.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want the error caused by the user not picking a file not to happen at all. First of all we have to investigate why the error happens. You are simply using the `OpenFileDialog.FileName` before you checked if it is valid. So if the user clicked cancel the error will happen.

Something like this should be better:

```
If File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then

    'All the code in the function in your image here...

End If
```

Hope that helps. Your question came out very cryptic.